# Convert java data object to service object

Tags: java, object, optimization

When writing a service we generally tend to have a separation between data object(ORM) and service object(one that is marshalled into a JSON/XML etc.) and end up writing a converter that takes data object(s) as input and produces service object(s). The converter does nothing but gets data from data object using getters and sets some of them into the service object.

I hope most people would be able to relate to this process.
I want to know if JDK has anything to optimize this scenario.

I am thinking more in terms of the optimized array copy where jvm does it at a System level.

Answer (score 2):

What you call "data object" is usually called an "entity". What you call "service object" is usually called a "data transfer object" ("DTO").

Those two are Java objects like all the other Java objects, and the JVM doesn't have any specific thing to optimize the transformation of entities to DTOs.

This process is extremely fast anyway compared to the cost of executing a SQL query and get back entities, and serializing DTOs to send them over the network. If you have something to optimize, it's probably not the transformation of entities to DTOs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Serializable` interface, and then read object with `ObjectInputStream` and write with `ObjectInputStream`. But much prettier is use `DataInput/OutputStream` for serialization.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataInputStream.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/DataOutputStream.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectInputStream.html
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/ObjectOutputStream.html